# What to do with old questions whose only 'complete' answerer gives no clarification?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I've had a few questions where I only received one response, and while they answered my question (at least partially), I had some doubts about it, and left a comment (while upvoting, but not accepting the answer).

But many of those times, my comments are never answered, and I'm kept in doubt about some concept or resource used in the answer.

Should I accept the answer in those cases?

Comment: Don't accept an answer when you have doubt. You may leave a comment again or set up a bounty.

Comment: Despite the fact that it is not what you are asking here, I will point out two things. It is ok to ask a new questions which asks about some particular step in an answer to an older question: See [Clarify an old answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer). If you have some question where you need more input from other users, there might be some things you can try to do. (Of course, there is no guarantee that they will help.) See: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478)

Comment: I assume by "old" question you mean months old?  If it's only a week old, maybe that guy didn't check M.SE this week and will come back soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**, you should not accept answers which do not explain all your doubts.

If you want a better, clarified answer, but feel like you're annoying people with too many comments, edit in the question the parts you want clarified and set some generous bounty on the question.